# Keep multiple space-aligned `set(VARIABLE value)` the way they were during cmake-format

Tags: cmake, code-formatting, cmake-format

We have a lot of CMake files that contain `set()`-sequences like

```
set(VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(VERSION_MINOR 2)
set(VERSION_ABI   3)
set(VERSION_PATCH 0-rc2)
```

I can't find a for `cmake-format` to keep things aligned like that; it will always condense the repeated whitespaces (here, after `_ABI`) into one.

Is there a way to tell `cmake-format` to keep this alignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest simply disabling cmake-format locally around these few lines. See the manual: https://cmake-format.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format-features.html?highlight=disable#disable-formatting-locally

```
# cmake-format: off
set(VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(VERSION_MINOR 2)
set(VERSION_ABI   3)
set(VERSION_PATCH 0-rc2)
# cmake-format: on
```